# Convergence of a sequence constructed from an already convergent sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

This problem states that a sequence a_n converges to a limit L. It then asks if the following sequence converges and to prove if it does, or give a counterexample.

The sequence is a1, a2, a2, a2, a3, a3, a3, a3, a3... and so on with the terms of an appearing 2k-1 times.

I understand that that starting off that for any positive epsilon, there exists N in the natural numbers such that n>N implies that |an - L| < epsilon, but I don't know how to translate that into proving that the second sequence converges. It might not also converge, as it asks to provide a counterexample.

I'm thinking that I could start off with the fact that all converging series are bounded, therefore there exists an M for an such that an < M for every n. However it is not necessarily the case that all bounded sequences are convergent.

Comment: HINT: Let $M=N^2$, can you prove for all $n>M$ we have $|L-b_n|<\varepsilon$ where $b_n$ is the new sequence? Note that the sum of the first $k$ odd numbers is equal to $k^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Given $N$ for the original sequence then $N'=\sum_{k=1}^N (2k-1)= N(N+1)-N=N^2$ will be what you need for the new sequence, i.e. for $m\gt N^2$, $|b_m-L|\lt \epsilon$, where $b_m$ is the $m^{th}$ term in the expanded sequence.